# How can I get the x,y coordinate location of a tile in the tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just started getting used to using Unity's new tilemap tool (UnityEngine.Tilemaps).

One issue I am having is that I don't know how to get the x,y coordinates of a placed tile via script. I am trying to move a scriptableObject on the tilemap in script to a new location that the player clicks, but I don't know how to get the coordinates of the clicked tile location. There doesn't seem to be any position property for the Tile class (the Tile knows nothing about its location), so the Tilemap must have the answer. I was not able to find anything in the Unity documentation for how to get the Vector3 coordinates for a selected tile in the Tilemap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get the Grid's position from mouse click, so instead I used a Raycast to `Vector3`, and then converted that to coordinates via the `WorldToCell` method of the Grid component as per Shirotha's suggestion. This allows me to move the selected `GameObject` to a new position.

```c#
public class ClickableTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NormalTile normalTile;
    public Player selectedUnit;

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // left click - get info from selected tile
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            // get mouse click's position in 2d plane
            Vector3 pz = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            pz.z = 0;

            // convert mouse click's position to Grid position
            GridLayout gridLayout = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
            Vector3Int cellPosition = gridLayout.WorldToCell(pz);

            // set selectedUnit to clicked location on grid
            selectedUnit.setLocation(cellPosition);
            Debug.Log(cellPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

On an aside, I know how to get the Grid location, but now how to query it. I need to get the GridSelection static object from Grid, and then get its position.

Comment: Could you share the implementation of this ClickableTile? I need to do the same thing as the OP but I'm pretty new to Unity.

Comment: ahh you are the OP :) Anyway I had some success adapting your code above. I needed to make sure my tilemap was aligned to a Unity cell boundary (i.e a whole number) and also add/subtract from the cellPosition.x and cellPosition.y as appropriate for my tilemap.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to the `Tile` instance you can use its transform (or the raycast hit from the click) to get its world position and than get the tile coordinates via the `WorldToCell` method of your `Grid` component (look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html)).

**EDIT:**

Unity seems to not instantiate the tiles but instead uses only one tile object to manage all tiles of that type, i wasn't aware of that.

To get the correct position you have to calculate it yourself. Here is an example of how to get the tile position at the mouse cursor if the grid is positioned at the xy-plane with z = 0

```cs
// get the grid by GetComponent or saving it as public field
Grid grid;
// save the camera as public field if you using not the main camera
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
// get the collision point of the ray with the z = 0 plane
Vector3 worldPoint = ray.GetPoint(-ray.origin.z / ray.direction.z);
Vector3Int position = grid.WorldToCell(worldPoint);
```

Comment: I'm going to try the raycast method thanks, I don't think I can use the Tile instance's transform. From my knowledge, the tiles in my Tilemap have no knowledge of their location in the grid. I have a script called ClickableTile that is linked to the Tilemap Game Object, and it has the Tile ScriptableObject passed in. The script does some action on click and I do have access to the Tile ScriptableObject, but I'm not sure how to get the 'instance' and whether it knows about its position. Using the documentation linked gives me a (0,0,0) no matter where I click

Comment: Shirotha I understand your edit, but I don't see how a Tile can know about its position. The code above will set a Vector3Int for the CustomTile ScriptableObject, but the Unity Tilemap tool is used to brush this CustomTile across many grid cells. The 'position' would always return a static value. I think you need to use the Grid to get the position, which I haven't figured out