# How can I get the tile gameObject by position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277320/how-can-i-get-the-x-y-coordinate-location-of-a-tile-in-the-tilemap), so I can get the grid's position from mouse click.

I want to destroy a tile and move player to the grid's position by mouse click.

I have 2 problems which I don't know how to solve.

1. After I get a grid's position, how can I get the tile gameObject?
2. When I set player.transform.position to the grid's position,
   it look like [PNG-A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAU1Q.png), but what I want is like [PNG-B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DonaX.png), 
   at the center of the tile's x position.

If you don't understand, I'm sorry for that, I'm not good in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. After I get a grid's position, how can I get the tile gameObject?

Use `Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject`:

```cs
Tilemap tilemap; // Given
Vector3Int pos;  // Given
GameObject gameObjectAtPosition = tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject(pos);
```

> 2. When I set player.transform.position to the grid's position, it look like PNG-A, but what I want is like PNG-B, at the center of the tile's x position.

Add half of the tile's width (`0.5 * GridLayout.cellSize.x`) to the x of the position you are getting right now. You can use `Vector3.Scale` to do this:

```cs
GameObject person;    // Given
Vector3 tilePosition; // Given
person.transform.position = tilePosition + Vector3.Scale(new Vector3(0.5f,0f,0f), GridLayout.cellSize) ;
```

Comment: And I change 1. to `print(GetComponent<Tilemap>().GetInstantiatedObject(pos).name)`?

Comment: but I get an error  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`?
Do you have any idea what causes this error?

Comment: @raxabizze What line does that happen on? It means that something on the left of a `.` is `null` Also just as a piece of advice you should be avoiding calling `GetComponent` in `Update` methods or in methods that are used in `Update` whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful.